# Convert string literals in an array to variable name

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, literals

I'm new to javascript.  I am trying to store object variable names in an array but the way I'm doing it, the array values become strings.  Is there a way to change these values from strings to the object variable names?  In the following code, the last statement is what I would like to use but it generates "undefined" because, I think, it's seen as a string.  Thanks!

```
var plan1 = {
  name: "Lisa",
  price: 5.00,
  space: 100
}

var plan2 = {
  name: "John",
  price: 2.00,
  space: 150    

}

var myArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  myArray[i] = "plan" + (i + 1);
}

alert(plan2.name);
alert(myArray[1].name);
```

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't sound well. Your application design is already broken if you have to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: it's a very bad style, try to avoid it. Look at http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html

You can consider using `eval`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  myArray[i] = eval("plan" + (i + 1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works and I've read a few other comments that relay the same assessment you've made regarding its use.  I still don't understand why it's considered, "...bad style."  Nevertheless, for my initial use, this is meant to be used in a rough prototype.  So far this bit of it is enough to continue building.  Assuming the finished prototype passes muster, then professionals will take over.  :-)

Comment: It's a bad style because you consider all objects plan1, plan2, ... to be part of the same dataset. If it is so you better put them in single object: ```var plans = {1: {...smth...}, 2: {...smth else...}}```. It's just harder to control all these separate variables. What if you need to copy all of them or do smth else? And eval is a bad practice too because you can easily add unnecessary complexity with it, just moving some logic inside eval call bit by bit.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and recommendation!

Answer (score 1):

You can't build the name like you are trying to do and get it to store the object with the same name. What you have in `myArray` is the strings `"plan1"` and `"plan2"`.
 You would have to do something like `myArray[0] = plan1;  myArray[1] = plan2;`  Then it should work in the array like you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to do that programmatically. Just build your array literal out of the parts that you want it to contain:

```
var plan1 = {
  name: "Lisa",
  price: 5.00,
  space: 100
};
var plan2 = {
  name: "John",
  price: 2.00,
  space: 150 
};
var myArray = [plan1, plan2];
```

Or even don't use those variables for the objects at all, and directly put them in the array structure:

```
var myArray = [{
  name: "Lisa",
  price: 5.00,
  space: 100
}, {
  name: "John",
  price: 2.00,
  space: 150    
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
myArray[i] = window["plan" + (i + 1)];
```

working copy at http://plnkr.co/edit/7pY4Lcmx6wN1rQk9rklu?p=preview

Comment: Why do you think `plan1` is a global variable?

Comment: This is assuming they are global scope variables. will have to modify it accordingly if not.
you may be better off doing something like this
http://plnkr.co/edit/7pY4Lcmx6wN1rQk9rklu

Comment: i am sure it is in his case.

Comment: Doesn't work for local variables. It can be done using eval for both global and local variables.